# The best method for handling bibtex files

Tags: python

I have a bibtex file that contains roughly 640 entries (rising tendency). I use Jabref to maintain this file. Actually I want to clean up things and do stuff, where Jabref cannot help. So I thought writing a code and be as flexible as possible.

Some tasks are e.g. which articles have a missing "file" entry or "title" entry? Which articles have the same file entry, etc.

My approach was populating a list of dictionaries. Dictionary contains the information of one article in the bibtex file. For example:

```
elements = [{
'author': 'Ando, K. and Ota, H. and Oki, T',
'comment': 'modelling, fundamental diagram, plane, cellular automata',
'file': 'Ando1988.pdf',
'issue': '2',
'journal': 'Railway R',
'owner': 'bob',
'timestamp': '2008.01.09',
'title': 'Forecasting the flow of people',
'type': 'ARTICLE',
'volume': '45',
'year': '1988'},
{'author': "Helbing, D. and Farkas, I. J. and Moln\\'{a}r, P. and Vicsek, T",
'booktitle': 'Pedestrian and Evacuation Dynamics',
'editor': 'Schreckenberg, Michael and Scharma, Som Deo',
'file': 'Helbing2002.pdf',
'key': 'Helbing2002',
'owner': 'jack',
'publisher': 'Springer',
'timestamp': '2007.12.12',
'title': 'Simulation of pedestrian crowds in normal and evacuation situations',
'type': 'INPROCEEDINGS',
'year': '2002'
}]
```

My functions that operate on this structure start always with something like

```
for element in elements:
   do_stuff with element
```

Although my code works fine, but somehow I have a feeling that I'm doing things *brute force wise*. This why I would like to initiate a discussion and ask you:

1. Is there a neater/smarter/elegant structure than the one I'm using
   (list of dictionaries)?
2. How would you organize the data such that
   processing the information becomes easier.

**EDIT:** I would like to mention that due to different type of articles (BOOK, PROCEEDINGS, ARTICLE, etc) and because I m only human, the dictionaries may have different keys and different numbers of keys.

Comment: As a general rule, whenever you have a whole bunch of dictionaries with the same set of keys, it goes more with the grain of the language (Python, that is) to make them into instances of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries are good for dealing with unpredictable key-value pairs. Objects are good for dealing with predictable key-value pairs (in fact, in Python, you can store arbitrary properties in your own objects).

The main advantages that classes and objects *might* give you:

1. If you want to pre-define the different types of entries, and check that your data conforms to that schema, classes, and class hierarchies will make this easier
2. If you have a lot of operations that depend on figuring out how to process each dictionary, then this can likely be made cleaner with inheritance and polymorphic functions.
3. If you find that you want to add collections as values to your hashtable, you will likely start to find writing methods on objects easier.

You can also keep all the data inside your classes in dicts if you find that easier.

You could also take a bunch of code over to codereview.stackexchange and see if you like their suggestions for refactoring into objects.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I' use Python for  doing things quickly. For this reason I never thought of using is Object-oriented. I will think about it.